# pyqt4 : Can I override a method without subclass?

Tags: overriding, pyqt4, subclass

I hope to change "keyPressEvent()" method of QWidget.
Undoubtedly, I create a new class inherits "QWidget", it can do that.
But, I have a returned QWidget from a method. So, I can't manage returned "QWidget" with subclass.
How can I make my own "keyPressEvent()" method of QWidget?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install an [event filter](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#eventFilter) on the widget, and trap the [KeyPress](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qevent.html#Type-enum) event:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.widget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        self.widget.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.widget.installEventFilter(self)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.widget)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if (event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress and
            source is self.widget):
            print('key pressed: %s' % event.text())
            return True
        return QtGui.QWidget.eventFilter(self, source, event)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    window.resize(320, 240)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Note that the example returns `True` for all key presses, which stops any further processing of those events. If you just want to "listen" for events without processing them, make sure the `eventFilter` returns `False`.

Comment: I checked! You always show me the way!! I REALLY REALLY thank you for your care